# How to control on which pages the Aldehyde theme's main slider is shown?

Tags: theme-development

The [Aldehyde theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/aldehyde/) is a nice open source theme that comes with a main slider that can be configured in the template's settings. By default, it is shown on the blog page, whether that is the homepage or a static page set via the WordPress "reading settings".

I want to show it instead on multiple other, specific pages. How to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be configured in the theme settings. You will need a bit of coding:

1. In your WordPress backend, with the Aldehyde theme set as the active one, navigate to "Design → Editor".
2. In the "Templates" column on the right, select `slider-nivo.php`.
3. You will find that the first non-comment line looks like this:

   ```
   if ( … && is_blog() ) :
   ```

   Change the condition to meet your needs. You can use the [is_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) function to make the slider show on pages with the given page slugs / IDs:

   ```
   if ( … && is_page(array('page1', 'page2', 21, 23)) ) :
   ```
4. Of course for a clean solution, put this change into a child theme.